# Unable to Update the Namespace of XML Document

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, namespaces

I have a program that generates XML Output.
The program with default namespace looks like this:

```
<n0:eCPR xmlns:n0="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd" 
         xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:DV4:/1SAI/TAS1F59A417878D36573F1D:700:2013/05/24">
  <n0:contractorInfo>
   <n0:contractorName>test_user</n0:contractorName>
   <n0:contractorAddress>
    <n0:street></n0:street>
    <n0:city></n0:city>
    <n0:state/>
    <n0:zip/>
   </n0:contractorAddress>
 </n0:contractorInfo>
</n0:eCPR>
```

If i remove the default namespace, the output looks like this

```
<eCPR>
  <contractorInfo>
    <contractorName>test_user</contractorName>
    <contractorAddress>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <state/>
     <zip/>
   </contractorAddress>
   <insuranceNum></insuranceNum>
   <contractorEmail></contractorEmail>
 </contractorInfo>
</eCPR>
```

What i want it to look as

```
<CPR:eCPR xmlns:CPR="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">
 <CPR:contractorInfo>
  <CPR:contractorName>test_user</CPR:contractorName>
  <CPR:contractorAddress>
   <CPR:street>999 Carrier Rd</CPR:street>
   <CPR:city>Oakland</CPR:city>
   <CPR:state>CA</CPR:state>
   <CPR:zip>94612</CPR:zip>
  </CPR:contractorAddress>
 </CPR:contractorInfo>
</CPR:eCPR>
```

The code i used to remove the default namespace was:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Kindly, help out.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the actual XML input?

Comment: @michael.hor257k i am reading the XSD and fetching values for each node and generating a XML Output. The initial output contains namspaces starting with sap:// as it is a SAP System. But, i want to update the namespace to CPR( As shown) . I removed the existing namespace but cannot update it. I have updated with the default output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your input has no attributes (or comments or processing instructions), I see no reason why you couldn't do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:CPR="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="CPR:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```